# How come Python3 typing.List is a subclass of list and list is also a subclass of typing.List?

Tags: python, list, typing

I tested this simple code and find something confuses me. Run the following code in Python 3.6 and both statements returns True. Why?

```
import typing
print(issubclass(list, typing.List))  # print True
print(issubclass(typing.List, list))  # print True
```

Can someone give me some explanation on this?

Comment: I think both are same classes. Typing.list and list both are same classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, `list` is not a subclass of `typing.List`. To see what `list` is actually a subclass of, you can take a look at its [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/):

```
>>> list.__mro__
(<class 'list'>, <class 'object'>)
```

On the other hand, the MRO of `typing.List` shows that it actually is a subclass of `list`, as well as of many other classes:

```
>>> typing.List.__mro__
(typing.List, <class 'list'>, typing.MutableSequence, <class 'collections.abc.MutableSequence'>, typing.Sequence, <class 'collections.abc.Sequence'>, typing.Reversible, <class 'collections.abc.Reversible'>, typing.Collection, <class 'collections.abc.Collection'>, <class 'collections.abc.Sized'>, typing.Iterable, <class 'collections.abc.Iterable'>, typing.Container, <class 'collections.abc.Container'>, typing.Generic, <class 'object'>)
```

### So, why does Python say that `list` is a subclass of `typing.List`?

Well, that is the whole point of `typing.List`. To pretend to be a base class of `list`.

### How is it done?

Using *Abstract Base Classes*. See what [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class) says about them:

> ABCs introduce virtual subclasses, which are classes that don’t
>   inherit from a class but are still recognized by isinstance() and
>   issubclass(); see the [abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#module-abc) module documentation.

You can see from its MRO that `typing.List` inherits from many ABC's, which list recognizes as its base classes, e.g.:

```
>>> issubclass(list, collections.abc.MutableSequence)
True
>>> issubclass(list, collections.abc.Collection)
True
>>> issubclass(list, collections.abc.Container)
True
```